# Converting categorical string to number

Tags: r

my data set looks like this

```
category number 
male        01
male        02
female      03
male        04
male        05
```

my question is how do I convert category column as `male=1` and `female=2`.
i want 1 in place of male and 2 in place of female

Comment: from the duplicate post, `(a == "female") + 1` would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
levels(df$category)[c("male","female")] <- c(1,2)
```

If you wanted a numeric vector:

```
df$category <- as.numeric(df$category)
```

This should solve!

Comment: However, the variable `category` would remain `factor`...

Comment: Maybe he wanted to replace the factor levels. OP was not specific with his request.

Answer (score 0):

let's start with a reproducible example:

```
x = data.frame(category = c("male", "male", "female", "male", "male"), 
               number = paste0("0", 1:5))
```

this will create a numeric vector with satisfying your needs:

```
x$cat_num <- as.numeric(factor(x$category, levels = c("male", "female")))
x
#   category number cat_num
# 1     male     01       1
# 2     male     02       1
# 3   female     03       2
# 4     male     04       1
# 5     male     05       1
```